# android ViewPager With Fragment Volley request on a null object reference error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

hi i have a viewPager with some lists on it and lists data comes from server and when i change the pages few times this error comes this is my code so far
here  error

```
01-15 12:11:48.512 9508-9508/app.mma.introsliderproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: app.mma.introsliderproject, PID: 9508
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at app.mma.PokerInfo.lastWorldNews.LastWorldNewsFragment$4.onResponse(LastWorldNewsFragment.java:122)
                                                                              at app.mma.PokerInfo.lastWorldNews.LastWorldNewsFragment$4.onResponse(LastWorldNewsFragment.java:117)
```

and my viewPager setOffScreenLimit is 4 and my Pager Pages is 7 
and this is LastWorldNews Fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_last_world_news,container,false);
    prepareData();
    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_world_news);
    pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progresslastnews);
    refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.refresh_news);
    btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_retry_last_news);
    tv = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_last_news);
    ConnectivityInit(HIDE);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (CheckInternet.isOnline(getContext())){
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getUrl("lastWorldNews");
                ConnectivityInit(HIDE);
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prepareData();
            }
        }
    });
    refresh.setColorSchemeColors(
            R.color.material_green_200,
            R.color.material_green_400,
            R.color.material_green_600,
            R.color.material_green_800
    );
    refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            prepareData();
            refresh.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

private void prepareData() {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            LastWolrdNewsParser parser = new LastWolrdNewsParser();
            ArrayList<LastWorldNews> news = parser.ParseJson(response);
            LastWorldNewsAdapter adapter = new LastWorldNewsAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    R.layout.last_world_news_list_item,news);
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (mListView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE || mListView.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });

    RequestQueue quew = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    quew.add(request);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (request != null){
        request.cancel();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (request != null){
        request.cancel();

    }
}
```

}
i want to change pageoffScreenLimit to 6 but i want to know is there any way better? and onDestroy and onPause methods is a standard way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

To

```
getActivity()
```

Remove `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Define variable `Context mContext;`

add this method to fragment

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }
```

This method will will initialize the contaxt fragment is attached to activity.
use `mContext` instead of `getApplicationContext()` method

Comment: @sadegh `prepareData();` method is called before initializing `pb = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progresslastnews);`. which is used in prepareData() method. This may cause error in future